# Could I write a new Frankenstein book since it's public domain?

Tags: public-domain

I was largely just wondering about this as there are a number of very fun, interesting things that could be done with the character.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mary Shelley's [Frankenstein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frankenstein) is indeed public domain so you are free to use that character.

[image]

However, a lot of what we think of as "Frankenstein" is not Mary Shelly, for example, the iconic Frankenstein look dates from the 1931 [film](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frankenstein_(1931_film)) which may still be under copyright.

You can use elements that are public domain, you can't use elements that aren't.